# Conditional For get_the_author_meta

Tags: post-meta, author

In post loop I'd like to setup a condition for get_the_author_meta.

So if the author meta field is empty, then nothing is displayed. Below is what I have but it's not working.

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter') ): ?>
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/<?php get_the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>" target="_blank">Twitter</a></p>
<?php else: ?>
<strong>No website</strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `get_the_author_meta()` returns the data for use in PHP. To display the
>   information instead, use `the_author_meta()`
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Your code does not `echo` data even if it is present. Add an `echo` or use [`the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('twitter') ): ?>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>" target="_blank">Twitter</a></p>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong>No website</strong>
<?php endif; ?>
```